# RegAsm dll no types registered

Tags: c#, dll, regasm

I am attempting to register a .dll using RegAsm. It is a .NET 2.0 dll. All classes are public and ComVisible is true. I am still getting the RA0000 : No types were registered error. Below is the code and assemblyinfo. Any help would be great, thanks!

STARTelnet.cs

```
/**
*Steven T. Norris     Created: 3/27/2012
*Last Updated By: Steven T. Norris     Last Updated On: 3/27/2012
*
*/

using System;
using MinimalisticTelnet;
using System.Net.Sockets;

/**
 * @brief Used to connect to, read, and respond to a STAR terminal session.
 * 
 * Steven T. Norris     Created: 3/27/2012
 */
namespace STARTelnet
{
    /**
     * Class used to connect to, read, and respond to a STAR terminal session. 
     */
    public class STARConnection
    {
        private TelnetConnection conn;
        private string output;
        private string command;
        private string prompt;

        /**
         * Instantiates new STARConnection. <br/>
         * Recommended login timeout is 2000. <br/>
         * Recommended overall timeout is 500. <br/>
         * Throws SocketException, PromptException, LoginException
         * 
         * @param [in] string username:Username for login
         * @param [in] string password:Password for login
         * @param [in] int loginTimeout:timeout milliseconds for login
         * @param [in] int overallTimeout:timeout milliseconds for session
         */
        public STARConnection(string username, string password, int loginTimeout, int overallTimeout)
        {
            output = "";
            conn = new TelnetConnection("HOSTHOSTHOST", 23);
            this.SetTimeout(overallTimeout);
            try
            {
                output = conn.Login(username, password, loginTimeout);
                if(output.Contains("You entered an invalid login name or password"))
                {
                    throw new LoginException("Failed to login");
                }
                this.ParsePrompt();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                if(e.Message.Contains("login prompt"))
                {
                    throw new PromptException("Login", "Could not find login prompt");
                }
                else if(e.Message.Contains("password prompt"))
                {
                    throw new PromptException("Password", "Could not find password prompt");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sets the timeout for the session in milliseconds
         * @param [in] int timeout:timeout for session
         */
        public void SetTimeout(int timeout)
        {
            conn.MainTimeOutMs = timeout;
            conn.TimeOutMs = timeout;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the current timeout for the session in milliseconds
         * @param [out] int:timout for session
         */
        public int GetTimeout()
        {
            return conn.TimeOutMs;
        }

        /**
         * Writes a command to the STAR session
         * @param [in] string command:command to write
         */
        public void Write(string command)
        {
            this.command = command;
            conn.Write(this.command);
            this.command = this.command.Replace("\n", "{newLine}");
        }


        /**
         * Writes a command followed by a new line (\n) to the STAR session
         * @param [in] string command:command to write
         */
        public void WriteLine(string command)
        {
            this.command = command;
            conn.WriteLine(this.command);
            this.command += "{newLine}";
        }

        /**
         * Reads output from STAR session. Assumes no data within given timeout denotes end of stream
         * @param [out] string:output from STAR session
         */
        public string Read()
        {
            output = conn.Read();
            this.ParsePrompt();
            return output;
        }

        /**
         * Reads output from STAR session with timeout changed for only this read. Assumes no data within
         * timeout denotes end of stream.
         * @param [in] int timeout:timeout for this read only
         * @param [out] string:output from STAR session
         */
        public string Read(int timeout)
        {
            int temp = this.GetTimeout();
            this.SetTimeout(timeout);
            this.Read();
            this.SetTimeout(temp);
            return output;
        }

        /*
         * Parse prompt from output
         */
        private void ParsePrompt()
        {
            prompt = output.Substring(output.LastIndexOf("\n") + 1);
        }

        /**
         * Gets output from last read
         * @param [out] string:output from last read
         */
        public string GetOutput()
        {
            return output;
        }

        /**
         * Gets last command entered
         * @param [out] string:last command entered
         */
        public string GetCommand()
        {
            return command;
        }

        /**
         * Gets prompt from last read
         * @param [out] string:last prompt
         */
        public string GetPrompt()
        {
            return prompt;
        }

        /**
         * Checks for connection
         * @param [out] bool:connection status
         */
        public bool IsConnected()
        {
            return conn.IsConnected;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exception for failed logins
     */
    class LoginException: Exception
    {

        private string offender = "";
        public LoginException() : base() { }
        public LoginException(string message) : base(message) { }

        /**
         * Creates exception
         * @param string offender:element causing exception
         * @param string message:exception message
         */
        public LoginException(string offender, string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            this.offender = offender;
        }

        /**
         * To String method for getting exception string
         * @param [out] string:string representation of exception
         */
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if(offender == "")
            {
                return this.GetType() + ": "+this.Message+"\n"+this.StackTrace;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Incorrect login: " + offender + "--" + this.Message + "\n" + this.StackTrace;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exception for failed STAR prompts
     */
    class PromptException: Exception
    {

        private string prompt = "";
        public PromptException() : base(){ }
        public PromptException(string message) : base(message){ }

        /**
         * Creates exeption
         * @param string prompt:prompt causing exception
         * @param string message:exception message
         */
        public PromptException(string prompt, string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            this.prompt = prompt;
        }

        /**
         * To String method for getting exception string
         * @param [out] string:string representation of exception
         */
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if(prompt == "")
            {
                return this.GetType() + ": " + this.Message + "\n" + this.StackTrace;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Prompt failed: " + prompt + "--" + this.Message + "\n" + this.StackTrace;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("STARTelnet")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("COMPANY")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("STARTelnet")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © COMPANY 2012")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("d7ae512d-c840-4ebc-8057-73a10f286225")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Try to compile your assembly as .NET 4.0. This is required for some complicated reason on how regasm registers and uses assemblies from different versions of .NET. Also try to adorn your class with COMVisible(true) attribute, maybe settings comvisibility for assembly is not enough. Are you using /codebase switch when registering?

Comment: I have to compile into a .NET 2.0 for compatability issues. I am not using /codebase, but I've noticed that used before. What is its purpose?

Comment: /codebase is required when you are not putting assembly into GAC so it will be used from it's current location. If you want an assembly in the GAC you need to assign strong name to it.

Comment: @Blablablaster What would be considered a strong name? Is the naming convention I use qualified enough?

Comment: strong name is a special token, here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx

Comment: Many thanks. I'll read up on that.

Comment: I would like to just add a note to this (old) post since I can't find another more recent/relevant issue and Google seems to like this one. But considering the use of third-party references like AntiXssLibrary in your project (especially COM interop for web apps), you might find a little suprise in `AntiXssAssemblyInfo.cs`, namely `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` that needs to be removed before you can register types for this DLL. Had to do a double-take before I realized they added this in there as part of Release and that I wasn't the one that put it in there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your problem is you have no default constructor. Please add the following code and call. This is based on [guidance from MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/csharpgeneral/thread/4b021da2-3fc7-4f20-b3d0-0f90491a232e).

**Calling Code (Will look different in COM of course)**

```
var connection = new STARConnection();
connection.Initialize(username, password, loginTimeout, overallTimeout);
```

**New Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Default constructor needed for COM. Set parameters with properties.
/// </summary>
public STARConnection()
{
}

public Initialize(string username, string password, int loginTimeout, int overallTimeout)
{
    output = "";
    conn = new TelnetConnection("HOSTHOSTHOST", 23);
    this.SetTimeout(overallTimeout);
    try
    {
        output = conn.Login(username, password, loginTimeout);
        if(output.Contains("You entered an invalid login name or password"))
        {
            throw new LoginException("Failed to login");
        }
        this.ParsePrompt();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        if(e.Message.Contains("login prompt"))
        {
            throw new PromptException("Login", "Could not find login prompt");
        }
        else if(e.Message.Contains("password prompt"))
        {
            throw new PromptException("Password", "Could not find password prompt");
        }
        else
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I added the default constructor and it registered with no issues.

Comment: I removed the part about the ComVisible attribute. Did you need that on the class or not? Based on what I re-looked up, Microsoft says all public, non-generic types are visible to COM as long as they have a default constructor and the assembly is ComVisible(true).

Comment: All I needed was the default constructor. Yeah all ComVisible are defaulted true (unless of course you're using visual studio, which explicitly sets all to false in the assemblyinfo.cs). I'm having a second issue though, but that's a seperate question I'll post up in a few minutes if I can find a solution.

Comment: I've opened a second question about another issue here. I'd appreciate the help if you can give it. You seem to know your stuff on COM and .NET dlls. It can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977882/regasm-dll-net2-0-to-net4-0#comment12749230_9977882

Comment: @steventnorris, I honestly don't know on that one. Sorry. :(