# RegAsm dll .net2.0 to .net4.0

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, regasm

I have a dll that registers fine using .Net2.0's regasm, but when attempting to register with a .NET4.0 regasm, I get the error "Could not load file or assembly '*FILENAMEHERE*' or one of it's dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:  0x8013515
Code and assembly are below

STARTelnet.cs

```
/**
*Steven T. Norris     Created: 3/27/2012
*Last Updated By: Steven T. Norris     Last Updated On: 3/27/2012
*
*/

using System;
using MinimalisticTelnet;
using System.Net.Sockets;

/**
 * @brief Used to connect to, read, and respond to a STAR terminal session.
 * 
 * Steven T. Norris     Created: 3/27/2012
 */
namespace STARTelnet
{
    /**
     * Class used to connect to, read, and respond to a STAR terminal session. 
     */
    public class STARConnection
    {
        private TelnetConnection conn;
        private string output;
        private string command;
        private string prompt;

        /**
         * Instantiates new STARConnection. <br/>
         * Recommended login timeout is 2000. <br/>
         * Recommended overall timeout is 500. <br/>
         * Throws SocketException, PromptException, LoginException
         * 
         * @param [in] string username:Username for login
         * @param [in] string password:Password for login
         * @param [in] int loginTimeout:timeout milliseconds for login
         * @param [in] int overallTimeout:timeout milliseconds for session
         */
        public STARConnection(string username, string password, int loginTimeout, int overallTimeout)
        {
            output = "";
            conn = new TelnetConnection("HOSTHOSTHOST", 23);
            this.SetTimeout(overallTimeout);
            try
            {
                output = conn.Login(username, password, loginTimeout);
                if(output.Contains("You entered an invalid login name or password"))
                {
                    throw new LoginException("Failed to login");
                }
                this.ParsePrompt();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                if(e.Message.Contains("login prompt"))
                {
                    throw new PromptException("Login", "Could not find login prompt");
                }
                else if(e.Message.Contains("password prompt"))
                {
                    throw new PromptException("Password", "Could not find password prompt");
                }
                else
                {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sets the timeout for the session in milliseconds
         * @param [in] int timeout:timeout for session
         */
        public void SetTimeout(int timeout)
        {
            conn.MainTimeOutMs = timeout;
            conn.TimeOutMs = timeout;
        }

        /**
         * Gets the current timeout for the session in milliseconds
         * @param [out] int:timout for session
         */
        public int GetTimeout()
        {
            return conn.TimeOutMs;
        }

        /**
         * Writes a command to the STAR session
         * @param [in] string command:command to write
         */
        public void Write(string command)
        {
            this.command = command;
            conn.Write(this.command);
            this.command = this.command.Replace("\n", "{newLine}");
        }


        /**
         * Writes a command followed by a new line (\n) to the STAR session
         * @param [in] string command:command to write
         */
        public void WriteLine(string command)
        {
            this.command = command;
            conn.WriteLine(this.command);
            this.command += "{newLine}";
        }

        /**
         * Reads output from STAR session. Assumes no data within given timeout denotes end of stream
         * @param [out] string:output from STAR session
         */
        public string Read()
        {
            output = conn.Read();
            this.ParsePrompt();
            return output;
        }

        /**
         * Reads output from STAR session with timeout changed for only this read. Assumes no data within
         * timeout denotes end of stream.
         * @param [in] int timeout:timeout for this read only
         * @param [out] string:output from STAR session
         */
        public string Read(int timeout)
        {
            int temp = this.GetTimeout();
            this.SetTimeout(timeout);
            this.Read();
            this.SetTimeout(temp);
            return output;
        }

        /*
         * Parse prompt from output
         */
        private void ParsePrompt()
        {
            prompt = output.Substring(output.LastIndexOf("\n") + 1);
        }

        /**
         * Gets output from last read
         * @param [out] string:output from last read
         */
        public string GetOutput()
        {
            return output;
        }

        /**
         * Gets last command entered
         * @param [out] string:last command entered
         */
        public string GetCommand()
        {
            return command;
        }

        /**
         * Gets prompt from last read
         * @param [out] string:last prompt
         */
        public string GetPrompt()
        {
            return prompt;
        }

        /**
         * Checks for connection
         * @param [out] bool:connection status
         */
        public bool IsConnected()
        {
            return conn.IsConnected;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exception for failed logins
     */
    class LoginException: Exception
    {

        private string offender = "";
        public LoginException() : base() { }
        public LoginException(string message) : base(message) { }

        /**
         * Creates exception
         * @param string offender:element causing exception
         * @param string message:exception message
         */
        public LoginException(string offender, string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            this.offender = offender;
        }

        /**
         * To String method for getting exception string
         * @param [out] string:string representation of exception
         */
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if(offender == "")
            {
                return this.GetType() + ": "+this.Message+"\n"+this.StackTrace;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Incorrect login: " + offender + "--" + this.Message + "\n" + this.StackTrace;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Exception for failed STAR prompts
     */
    class PromptException: Exception
    {

        private string prompt = "";
        public PromptException() : base(){ }
        public PromptException(string message) : base(message){ }

        /**
         * Creates exeption
         * @param string prompt:prompt causing exception
         * @param string message:exception message
         */
        public PromptException(string prompt, string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            this.prompt = prompt;
        }

        /**
         * To String method for getting exception string
         * @param [out] string:string representation of exception
         */
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if(prompt == "")
            {
                return this.GetType() + ": " + this.Message + "\n" + this.StackTrace;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Prompt failed: " + prompt + "--" + this.Message + "\n" + this.StackTrace;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("STARTelnet")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("COMPANY")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("STARTelnet")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © COMPANY 2012")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("d7ae512d-c840-4ebc-8057-73a10f286225")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Don't obfuscate error messages, HEXVALUEHERE doesn't help us help you.  Only use the version 4 Regasm when you've actually changed the project to target .NET 4.

Comment: The project can't be changed to .NET 4. It has to be a .NET2.0 for compatability issues. I was under the impression that .NET was backwards compatable. I've adjusted the hex code above.

Comment: Then why do you want to register it with version 4 Regasm instead of using version 2?

Comment: @SoMoS Some people in the system only have .NET 4.0. Some only have .NET2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat special rules apply to a COM server like yours.  The CLR in .NET 4 supports in-process side-by-side versioning for the CLR, allowing a process to host more than one version of the CLR.  This is particularly important for COM servers, it solves the CLR version injection problem that previously made it impossible to reliably create managed shell extensions.  CLR version 2 and earlier only supported one version of the CLR in a process.  With the side effect that whatever COM server loaded the CLR first, would make it impossible to load COM servers later that require a later version of the CLR.  Particularly bad if that first COM server loaded the 1.0 or 1.1 version of the CLR.

If you don't want to target .NET 4 then you'll have to ask users to install .NET 3.5 SP1 so the server can be registered.  You also have to provide a app.exe.config file for the client program to tell the CLR that you are aware that your COM server was built for an earlier version of the CLR and that it is okay to run it with the version 4 CLR.  Which prevents the version 2 CLR from being used.  The .config file should look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4"/>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Clearly you'll be ahead by targeting .NET 4 for users that only have 4.  And do keep in mind that you actually might prefer getting the version 2 CLR loaded if the client program is entirely native, that's probably the version you've tested your code with.  Version 4 is highly compatible but it does have a number of bug fixes for bugs that your code unintentionally might depend on.

Comment: Where do I find/edit the app.exe.config file for distribution to a users PC and how would I tie it to their RegAsm? I'm assuming this is somewhere in the "Framework" directory? The users would be registering this dll via RegAsm using their terminal window on their local PC.

Comment: You have to create it.  Notepad.exe will do fine.  It must be stored in the directory that contains the *client* application EXE, using the name of the client program.  So if c:\foo\bar.exe uses your COM server then you must create c:\foo\bar.exe.config

Comment: What do you mean uses my COM server? This is all run locally on a single users PC.

Comment: "Server" in this context doesn't mean "server machine".  You wrote an 'in-process COM server', that's just what it is called in COM terms.  As opposed to 'COM client', the program that uses your DLL.

Comment: So in order for a .NET 2.0 dll to be usable by .NET 4.0 applications, there must be a .exe.config file with each and every exe?

Comment: This is highly specific only to COM servers.  A regular .NET 2 DLL will work just fine in .NET 4 without any config.  But that requires the main program to be a .NET program as well.  There's no question about what version of the CLR will get used, the EXE program loads it.  If your main program is a .NET program as well, as you imply, then you should not create a COM server at all.  It is unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: I do not believe I understand the full definition of COM. What I need is a dll made from c# code that others can use in their vbscript or c# projects. I'd assume a simple .NET dll would work, but noticed all instructions stated ComVisible had to be true for this to work.

Comment: For vbscript, yes, you'll need [ComVisible].  For a C# project, no, you reference the assembly directly.

Comment: This still doesn't click for me why the RegAsm didn't register the dll then. If the config file of an .exe is what's needed for an individual .exe, the dll should still register with the .NET4.0 RegAsm. The .exe.config should be the job of the future coder using the dll, but the registrations should still work, correct?

Comment: Clearly it didn't register it because it fell over on a runtime error, "Operation is not supported".  Not something I've ever tried intentionally.

Comment: Well thanks for the help. It works fine if included as a resource in a .NET 4.0 project, so I suppose they'll have to go that route instead of registering if they have .NET 4.0.

Comment: @steventnorris Regasm registers the DLL for COM interop. When you reference a .NET assembly, you're not using COM interop. When you call it from a VB script, you need to use COM interop. So you only need regasm for your VB script scenario, not for using it in another .NET project.